# What is the recommended way to install plugin jars on AWS Neo4j Enterprise Edition

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

We've used the vanilla Neo4j Enterprise Edition cloud formation template on AWS.

This installed APOC and GDS for us - great.

However, it didn't install the jars that some functions need. We are getting this error:

> Neo4jError: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.json`: Caused by: apoc.util.MissingDependencyException: Cannot find the S3 jars in the plugins folder.
> Please put these files into the plugins folder :
>
> aws-java-sdk-core-x.y.z.jar
> aws-java-sdk-s3-x.y.z.jar
> httpclient-x.y.z.jar
> httpcore-x.y.z.jar
> joda-time-x.y.z.jar
>
> See the documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/import/web-apis/#_using_google_cloud_storage

What is the cleanest way to install these jars across all nodes in the cluster? For now we only have one node, but that may not always be the case.

Thanks!

I expected there to be an easy way to get these plugins installed without needed to ssh into each node and manually install